# Arduino uno r3 not powering up

Tags: arduino-uno

i bought two arduino uno r3 card (not original)
one is working perfectly:
[image: 1]
the other is not powering up (no led is lit), i did some measuring and i found that two usb connector pins on the board are shorted, how can i proceed to repair it taking in account that it works from time to time !
[image: 2]
thank you
More images:
[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Use a De-Solder and remove the solder that is shorting the two USB connector pins.

Comment: hi mathsman, there is no solder between the pins, i guess it's one of the electronic component of the board that is causing the two pins to short, but the problem is how to identify it

Comment: Is there any connection in the PCB itself?

Comment: yes, on of the pins is connected to ground

Comment: No, not that, I meant that is there a connection between the shorted USB pins on the PCB itself?

Comment: Check the board under a loop/microscope, to see if any components or connection look off. A short between 5v and GND is pretty difficult to detect. You can check the resistance on different location, and see if it's slightly lower/higher. The lower the resistance, the closer you are to the faulty component. But for that you'd need a high precision multimeter. My first guess is the electrolytic capacitor, but that's just a wild guess. Could you post a hi-res photo of the defective board?

Comment: If not, it is really difficult to do anything as almost all components in your board are surface mounted.

Comment: Hi @Gerben I don't suppose that everyone has a Microscope or Very High Resolution Cameras . Instead , a magnifying glass is much better.

Comment: ok i'll upload more photos in a few seconds

Comment: Take pictures with a Magnifying glass If you have no High Resolution Cameras.

Comment: Sorry. I meant loupe, not loop

Comment: no problem sir, i added two photos, 
http://s23.postimg.org/y8o4fj9mz/SAM_1432.jpg

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/6ukiv3khf/SAM_1434.jpg
the photos in the post are resized, check the direct link for full size photos
thanks

Comment: I see nothing that's obviously wrong. Can you be more specific about "works from time to time"? What happens if you power it from the Jack (only test for a few seconds, as there is no polyfuse, like there is on the USB)?

Comment: the first time i connected it it worked for a few seconds then went off, after disconnecting and reconnecting it a few times it worked again, i programmed it and everything was fine, and now it won't work again, thats what i meant by from time to time, for the jack it's the samething as the usb port, i plugged a 9v battery to it and it didn't work

Comment: oh man, it's working again right now, this is confusing
http://s30.postimg.org/aesf9tvgx/work.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though there may be material between at least one USB pin and the ground layer. This may be flux of solder 'splash'.

If visual inspection shows that this may be the case I would try **carefully** scratching with a sharp poibt (eg scriber) along at least the green arc on the image below. Be careful not to break intended conduction paths (eg as shown in black).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it's intermittent I'd try two things:

Easy: Briefly reheat each pin of the USB connector and it's pad, the goal being to make sure the solder joints are solid. Clean away any solder bridging the pads. Of course you can only reach the back side of the board, but this is an easy first step.

More thorough: If the first step didn't get it working, then try desoldering the USB connector, using a solder pump and desoldering braid to remove as much of the solder as possible from all four pins before you try to actually remove the part. Work slowly giving it time to cool between steps so you don't overheat anything. When the part is removed, inspect the top of the board and clean up any solder bridges. Inspect the bottom of the USB connector where it touches the board and clean it, too, if necessary. Then solder it onto the board again using as little solder as necessary to make solid connections.

Comment: i'm going to desolder the usb connector because i'm pretty sure it is the source of the problem, when i partially plug the usb cable it works. thanks